# Sources for multiple Stieltjes integral

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, integration

My research involves multiple Stieltjes integral or multiple Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. But after searching online, I can not find what I need. So I ask this question on which sources (books or papers) provide a detailed discussion of the above fields.

Comment: In Ash & Doleans-Dade, Probability and Measure Theory, the Lebesgue-Stiltjes measures in $R^n$ are presented. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: asked and answered on https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4042707/87355

Comment: On Math Stack Exchange, there are no enough answers either.